# Razor page styles not working after adding TagHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I added _ViewImports.cshtml file under Views folder in an MVC application.
After adding the below line, styles on my page stopped working.

`@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

When I look at the elements on the page in chrome browser, I don't see anything under styles section.

[Styles before adding Taghelper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux4rp.png)

[Styles after adding TagHelper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csK6Z.png)

Comment: That's odd because adding to _ViewImports.cshtml is additive to whatever was there before.  Nothing should have gone away.

Comment: @peterkellner I was able to fix the problem by using the right styles link from bootstrap website. Not sure why the styles were not applied properly after adding the addTagHelper. Could be something to do with the order of applying _ViewStart & _ViewImports. Still trying to figure out aspnet MVC. Will post the right reason if and when I know it.

Comment: Could be mixed up versions installed